# finding two adjacent cells using vlookup()

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

In preparing my data for an interpolation within an interval, I am using the MS Excel vlookup() function to find a *pair* of values that will define the interval for my interpolation.

The default behavior of vlookup() is to return the value that is closest (from below) to the one that I am passing it.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?CorrelationId=af88ebd8-da67-4337-b753-32e76fc061a3&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

So this syntax

> =VLOOKUP(A4,$J$4:$K$41,1,TRUE)

will identify, correctly, the lower limit of the interval for my future interpolation. Given the structure of the table in which I am looking for values, I already now that the value that will define the upper limit of the interval is *just below* the one returned by vlookup() as I wrote it above. That is, I'd additionally need the address of the value returned by vlookup() and return the value at the same column but at the row index +1.

What function would extract the address of the cell in which the value returned by vlookup() is?

Thank you very much in advance.
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH(A4,$J$4:$K$41,TRUE)+1` can retrieve position of cell. Use `INDEX` to pick desired value.

Comment: Italian version uses semicolons to delimit formula arguments, I replaced them with commas for future reference.